# Birtviewer with maven on weblogic Error with opening reports

Tags: maven, weblogic, birt

I am using birt 4.3.1 with maven and deploying on weblogic.I deployed  birtviewer in weblogic 
as "WebViewerExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"  and can open birtviewer with url `localhost:7001/WebViewerExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`..But on trying to open view example link or trying to open url `localhost:7001/WebViewerExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign` I got this very long error.

```
`Error 500--Internal Server Errororg.apache.axis.InternalException: org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:135)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.init(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:49)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:135)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.init(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.init(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:174)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.init(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
`
```

Any suggestion please.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is this class "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo" is distributed both in weblogic server and in a signed jar of BIRT.

The smartest solution would be to resolve all conflicts and keep only one version of each class, but this might be very challenging.

A quick workaround would be to unsign the jar:

- stop WebLogic
- in  libraries of the webViewer, locate the largest JAR file which should be named like org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.3.1<*buil-version*>.jar
- rename this .jar to .zip
- within the archive, open META-INF folder and remove files such *.RSA and *.SF
- rename .zip to .jar
- restart WebLogic

I hope it helps

Comment: you are a genius..Thank you very much..
But it ends with a error as in this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043660/birtviewer-maven-on-weblogic-error-with-opening-reports .Thanks in Advance

Comment: In this case, you should also remove the folder org/w3c inside the same jar file and restart the server. I hope it will do it

Comment: The  Error on that link is -
"java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate.register(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/rpc/encoding/SerializerFactory;Ljavax/xml/rpc/encoding/DeserializerFactory;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/axis/encoding/TypeMappingDelegate, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for interface javax/xml/rp"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/824674/dom).I didnt find org/w3c inside the jar .It works by using version org.eclipse.birt.runtime 4.3.1.v20130918-1142 instead of using 4.3.1
My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.webviewer</groupId>

   <artifactId>WebViewerExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Birt Viewer Maven Project</name>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

     <properties>
          <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version> 
          <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version> 
          <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
          <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version> 
     </properties>

     <repositories>
                    <repository>
                    <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                    </repository>

                        <repository>
                               <releases>
                                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                               </releases>
                               <snapshots>
                                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                                  <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                                  <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                               </snapshots>
                               <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
                               <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
                               <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
                            </repository>
     </repositories>

    <dependencies>


                                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
                         <version>4.3.1.v20130918-1142</version>
                        <!--<version>4.3.1</version>   this is what I used previously., which gives above posted error-->
                        </dependency>

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


        <build>

                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.xerces-2.9.0.jar</packagingExcludes>

                                        <source>1.6</source>
                                        <target>1.6</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0</version>
                        </plugin>



             </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```